# OData error: "A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available." when calling Azure Active Directory Graph API

Tags: asp.net, azure, active-directory, openid, azure-active-directory

Let's see if you experts have a clue of what's going on here.

### Context

We have a web application running on Azure Web Sites. This WebApp uses OWIN + OpenID Connect to authenticate users against an Azure Active Directory tenant. Also the application uses the Azure AD Graph API to collect some data of the directory.

We based our code on this sample project provided in GitHub: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet

### Issue

The WebApp was working perfectly some hours ago (authenticating to the AD and fetching data from the directory), but then the weirdest thing happened to us. Today we found that we could still authenticate against the AD but the Graph API was throwing errors almost randomly.

We traced the error down to a specific request, when trying to get a specific user by ObjectId in a synchronous way:

```
Claim claimObject = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(Helper.Constants.ADTenant.ObjectIdClaimType);
string userObjectID = claimObject == null ? string.Empty : claimObject.Value;
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
List<IUser> users = client.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId == userObjectID).ExecuteAsync()
    .Result.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

The thing is the last line throws an exception regarding the OData model:

```
"A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value."
```

We started slicing the last line of code into pieces as follows:

```
IReadOnlyQueryableSet<IUser> queryUsers = client.Users.Where(u => u.ObjectId == userObjectID);
IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedUserCollection = queryUsers.ExecuteAsync().Result;
List<IUser> users = pagedUserCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

And found the exception was throwing in this line:

```
IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedUserCollection = queryUsers.ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

Weirdest thing is that this line was executing fine yesterday and today started failing without explanation.

Does anyone know what are we doing wrong? Why did it start failing today?

### Remarks

We are using api-version=2013-11-8. We kept the Azure AD Graph API Client Library on version 1.0, as in the sample on GitHub.

Comment: Hi Marc.  Again apologies for the issue here.  Based on your remarks, we wanted to follow up with you about this.  The APIs you are using in the code snippets above suggest that you are using Graph Client Library 2.0 (which is tied to Graph REST API version 1.5).  The github samples also use version 2.0.  We wanted to check if you are sure that your production code uses api-version=2013-11-8 - especially seeing as the change we rolled back should ONLY have affected api-version 1.5...

Comment: Hi Dan, the Graph Client Library we have in production is 1.0 as stated by the properties of the dll in VS, but it was internally numbered as 2.0.5. We updated the dll to 2.0.6 through Nuget, deployed and everything started working fine again. We are still pointing to api-version=2013-11-8, or at least the configuration files in production are pointing to this version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem just now! I have an application which have been working for a couple of weeks and hasn't been changed. I've got it working by upgrading "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" from version 2.0.5 to 2.0.6

Comment: That was it! Upgrading the dll solved the issue. But now a question raised in my mind: why this changes on the API are not backward compatible? The 2013-11-8 api version is suposed to be a stable version, right?

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well; saved me some serious headaches... But I agree with @MarcJordana, why in the world is this a problem in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

Folks,

First of all - many apologies for introducing this problem. The underlying problem is that an entity (User entity in this case) was updated on the service side, with a new collection (AlternativeSignInNamesInfo).  Typically adding new entities, properties, collections and complex types should not cause a breaking change for the client library.  However due to an issue in ODatalib, unknown collections are not simply ignored.
I totally agree with the sentiment on this, and we absolutely do NOT want to have apps that take a dependency on the Graph Client Library be subject to ANY outages.  We are working with the ODatalib team  to get this issue rectified, so that this is no longer a problem with our Graph client library moving forward.

In the meantime we are in the process of rolling back our Graph service, so that 2.0.5 should start to work again.  Version 2.0.6 should also work - as long as you don't try and post to the new collection on the User object (AlternativeSignInNamesInfo).

UPDATE:  The Graph service has been rolled back.  I’ve also verified that getting a user through Graph Client Library 2.0.5 AND 2.0.6 both work.

Hope this helps and again sorry for any issues caused here.

Comment: I would like to suggest that the critical nature of this product requires that we have an easy means to be reminded of an impending change. Providing enough time to test to ensure that we do not encounter something like this again.

Comment: Good point Taylor.  We'll be locking down this version of the GCL and the service until we get the fix I mentioned above.  We'll likely tie a new version of the GCL to a new version of the service. The point is these service changes should NOT impact the client library.  Anyways - I'm going to follow up to ensure that we are running automated test with the client library as part of any service updates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes upgrading the graph client Nuget package to the latest 2.0.6 fixed this problem. I had a similar panic this morning too. It's an unbelievable fact that Microsoft rolled out a new version of the dll which breaks applications run on previous version!

Answer (score 0):

My team had similar experience. After installing 2.06 our code started working again. Took the entire day with first discovering, fixing, and then testing the solution.